# Matplotlib AttributeError when plotting multiple plots in multiple windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to plot, show and save multiple plots in `matplotplib`. So, I used

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1, y1 = [0,1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]
x2, y2 = [0,1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]
x3, y3 = [0,1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]
x4, y4 = [0,1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]
x5, y5 = [0,1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]
x6, y6 = [0,1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]

ax=plt.figure(1)
bx=plt.figure(2)
cx=plt.figure(3)
dx=plt.figure(4)
ex=plt.figure(5)
fx=plt.figure(6)
gx=plt.figure(7)

ax.axes.errorbar(x,y,yerr=std)
bx.axes.errorbar(x1,y1,yerr=std1)
cx.axes.errorbar(x2,y2,yerr=std2)
dx.axes.errorbar(x3,y3,yerr=std3)
ex.axes.errorbar(x4,y4,yerr=std4)
fx.axes.errorbar(x5,y5,yerr=std5)
gx.axes.errorbar(x6,y6,yerr=std6)

ax.figure.show(1)
bx.figure.show(2)
cx.figure.show(3)
dx.figure.show(4)
ex.figure.show(5)
fx.figure.show(6)
gx.figure.show(7)
```

and I got the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'errorbar'` and when I use `ax.errobar` instead of `ax.axes.errorbar` I get the error `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'errorbar'`
. So, I want to know what is the problem with my code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Figure.axes` is a list of `Axes` (not an instance of one, because you can have more than one `Axes` object for each figure). You can get at the axes by indexing into it:

```
ax.axes[0].errorbar(x,y,yerr=std)
```

Depending on your set-up, you might also have to add the axes first (e.g. if you get an `IndexError`).
The [documentation for `Figure`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html?highlight=figure#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes) has more details.

Comment: Thanks. I read the documentation for `Figure` but I didn't get how would that work for me with `fig.add_axes(ax)` .

Comment: Did yout try adding the `[0]` to pull the `Axes` instance out of the `axes` list?

Comment: Yes I did and I got the index Error, so I referred to the `Figure` documentation and didn't know how adding axes will help or how to do it